# combine with groupByKey with unbound stream

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Pipeline is:

```
  1. PCollections<String> readTopic = PubSubIO.readString() ...
  2. PCollection<String> windowSession = readTopic.apply(Window.<String>into(Sessions
                                .withGapDuration(Duration.standardHours(1))));
  3.PCollection<KV<post, user> KVparsedPosts= windowSession.apply(ParDo.of(new 
     ParseEventFn());
  4. PCollection<KV<post, Iterable<user>> iterableKV= 
                        KVparsedPosts.apply(GroupByKey.create())
  5.PCollectionList<KV<post, Iterable<user>>listPosts = 
        iterableKV.apply(Combine.globally(new CombinePosts()).withoutDefaults())
  6.listPosts.apply(ParDo.of(new writePosts())
```

The input is a message which represents one user with array of posts relevant for that user,
Post is not unique(the same post can be relevant for many users)
my problem is with step 5 combine,  am not sure how to combine KV<...> to list so the `writePost` will write to D.B. batch of posts and not just one post,

**Example**: suppose we have Users: A,B,C and Posts: 1,2,3,4
and there are the messages we read from PubSub:

```
{user:a, posts:[1,2,4]}
{user:b, posts:[2,3]}
{user:c, posts:[2,4]}
```

I want to combine like this:

```
{post:1, user:[a]}
{post:2, user:[a,b,c]}
{post:3, user:[b]}
{post:4, user:[a,c]}
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do with the Combine? Maybe give an example?

Comment: added example  for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it looks like you've already figured out how to modify your elements to get the expected result in your example, and the only remaining issue you have is how to batch multiple posts together, correct?

I'll go over my suggested approach for your example (which matches your existing code), as well as for the batching of multiple posts.

**Step 1:** Create a ParDo from a custom DoFn that inverts the list of users and posts into KVs of <post, user>. For example:

```
{user:a, posts:[1,2,4]} -> {post:1, user:a}, {post:2, user:a}, {post:4, user:a}
```

You seem to already do that on this line: `3. PCollection<KV<post, user> KVparsedPosts= windowSession.apply(ParDo.of(new ParseEventFn());`

**Step 2:** Perform a GroupByKey, with the post as the Key. For example:

```
{post:2, user:a}, {post:2, user:b}, {post:2, user:c} -> {post:2, user:[a,b,c]}
```

You seem to be doing that on this line: `4. PCollection<KV<post, Iterable<user>> iterableKV= KVparsedPosts.apply(GroupByKey.create())`

**Step 3 (optional):** With the code above you can write one post at a time to the database. If you want to batch multiple posts, you will need to group multiple posts into batches, which can be done with the [GroupIntoBatches](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupIntoBatches.html) transform. In order to use this transform, you will need to assign all elements a placeholder key to batch them by, which can be done with [WithKeys](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/WithKeys.html). For example:

```
PCollection<KV<post, Iterable<user>> iterableKV =
        KVparsedPosts.apply(GroupByKey.create());

// Apply a key of 0 to every element.
PCollection<KV<Integer, KV<post, Iterable<user>>>> keyedPosts =
        iterableKV.apply(WithKeys.of(0));

// Group all elements into batches of 5 posts.
PCollection<KV<Integer, Iterable<KV<post, Iterable<user>>>>> batchedPosts =
        keyedPosts.apply(GroupIntoBatches.<Integer, KV<post, Iterable<user>>>ofSize(5));
```

Once batched, the placeholder key can be dropped and any followup work can be done.

Comment: thanks for your answer I'll look into it,  can you explain why not use combine ?

Comment: No specific reason, just that it doesn't seem needed for any of the steps. GroupByKey works fine when all you need to do is group values together. Combine on the other hand is useful when you have to do more complex types of aggregations.